# Diferença do QT contra o GTK+ em recursos

Tags: c++, qt, gtk

Antes de iniciarmos algumas considerações:

- O objeto deste tópico é buscar por fatos/objetos, portanto
  suposições/chutes/flames não serão aceitos como respostas.
- Todas as respostas devem levar em consideração um ambiente GNU/Linux com a
  devida biblioteca sem necessidade de se preocupar com portabilidade para ambiente não UNIX-LIKE (Windows/Mac).
- As respostas não necessitam considerar utilização da biblioteca para fim comercial.

---

Tenho visto bastante discussões em alguns foruns a cerca do uso das bibliotecas e fiquei com algumas duvidas quanto a certos argumentos.

1. Quais recursos exatamente o `GTK+` tem que o `QT` não tem?
2. E o inverso, quais recursos o `QT` tem que o `GTK+` não tem?
3. Percebi que ainda existe uma resistencia por parte do desenvolvedores na utilização das novas versões das bibliotecas. Tanto a QT quanto a GTK possuem versões novas. Há algum problema de compatibilidade com relação as versões anteriores que impedem o seu uso?

Comment: Você tomou bastante cuidado para fazer a pergunta, o que é louvável já que o jeito dela é sensível. Ainda vejo algum problema nela. Ela me parece ampla nos itens 1 e 2. E os itens 3 e 4 pedem opinião de forma explícita apesar de não usar esta palavra. Posso dizer que sua última dúvida não é importante já que a forma como o programador usa vai fazer mais diferença que a biblioteca em si. Eu já ouvi alguma coisa mas nunca comprovação já que é bem difícil comparar coisas tão amplas e tão interligadas que o GTK tem uma pequena vantagem em relação à Qt. Não ouvi sobre o GTK+ (*binding* p/ C++).

Comment: @bigown Obrigado pelo seu comentário. Fiz uma pequena edição nas perguntas tentando deixar mais explicito o objetivo em si.

Comment: "GTK+, ou GIMP Toolkit é um kit de ferramentas multi-plataforma para criar **interfaces gráficas**" e "Qt é um **framework** multiplataforma **para UI e aplicativos**, para desenvolvedores usando C++ ou QML" (grifo meu). Basicamente o 1o é GUI, o 2o é um framework extensivo que tem GUI e mais uma imensidão de coisas. Vai ser complicado uma comparação equilibrada de coisas com naturezas e objetivos um tanto diferentes.

Comment: Melhorou realmente, eu estava até tentando responder mas ainda os itens 1 e 2 exigiria uma compilação extremante longa ou então seria uma resposta incompleta. Na verdade não sei se alguém pode atestar que a resposta está correta realmente. Se tiver uma lista parcial, está valendo? Mas se valer, então pode ser tendencioso. No fundo o trabalho que dá para alguém responder é o mesmo que você pegar as duas documentações e fazer uma comparação. Não é algo que uma pessoa sem conhecimento não consiga fazer. Infelizmente ainda não achei uma forma desta pergunta ser considerada válida.

Comment: E tem essa questão que o Bacco está falando também. Mesmo que você escolha analisar só a parte GUI da Qt, o que poderia deixá-la em desvantagem pela arquitetura que ela usa, ainda teria que fazer uma análise muito longa ou cada um pegaria os pontos que **achasse** relevante.

Comment: Alias eu cometi um erro ali em cima. O problema de ser GTK ou GTK+ não tem nada a ver. Como você está perguntando por C++ e faz tempo que não ponho a mão em GTK, não lembrava mais que GTK+ é o GTK mesmo com nova nomenclatura. Eu estava pensando que você estava falando do gtkmm que é o *binding* p/ C++. Então a coisa ficou pior, porque você está comparando uma solução para C com outra para C++. Só para te ajudar um pouco, já tentaram fazer essa comparação e ficou bem ruim: http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/GTK_vs_Qt

Comment: Tentaram responder e não deu nenhuma informação relevante para sua pergunta: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129355/what-is-difference-between-gtk-and-qt-applications. Nessa pergunta também: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441127/gui-development-qt-vs-gtk. Sempre que muda uma versão maior, é possível que tenha algumas incompatibilidades. Um jeito diferente de fazer as coisas. Algumas pessoas não ficam confortáveis com isto e preferem ficar na versão antiga. A Qt 5 está ótima. Ouvi dizer que o GTK novo tem alguma desvantagem mas não lembro o que é e não sei se é verdade.

Comment: @bigown Obrigado pelos comentários. Vou fechar a pergunta uma vez que entendo não fazer muito sentido realizar a comparação como eu estava pensando.